# How can I access the elements of a "row" from a python dictionary without using numpy array

Tags: python, dictionary, matrix

I have a dictionary where each key corresponds to a list with the same number of values. I am treating each list as a "column". Using the values in each list, I am trying to write a linear approximation function. It works except when I run into the problem of a value repeating in a list. When I use indexof, it returns a y value that corresponds to the first occurrence of the x value passed in and not the actual y value that is at the same index in it's own list as the x value's index in it's respective list. Do I change my dictionary into a numpy matrix? Or is there a way to do this using a dictionary.

```
def calc_target(x1, x2, type1, type2, X):
    """Uses linear approximation to return a calculated
       value for the passed in type using a target value.

    Keyword arguments:
    x1 -- first x value
    x2 -- second x value
    type1 -- type of value to be calculated
    type2 -- type of value passed in
    X -- target value
    """
    y2 = float(data[type1][data[type2].index(str(x2))])
    y1 = float(data[type1][data[type2].index(str(x1))])
    print 'X:'
    print x1
    print x2
    print 'Y:'
    print y1
    print y2
    slope = (y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1)
    print slope
    return slope * (X - x1) + y1
```

[image]
For example, if my x values are 3 and the second 2 in the list corresponding to key 2, how can I make sure I'm getting 21 as the y value for 2 and not 24. Since if I use indexof, it will just return the corresponding value at the first instance of 2 which will be 24 and not 21.

Comment: Dictionaries only have a *single value* for each key, and they do not have "rows". It is entirely unclear what you are talking about, and it would be helpful if you posted example data.

Comment: You are looking for ordered datatype behavior from an unordered type. Dictionaries, as juanpa pointed out, only use unique keys as identifiers, rather than positional indexes. A numpy array will probably be preferable in this situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are iterating through the lists, you can iterate through both at the same time like

```
for value1, value2 in zip(dictionary_name[key1],dictionary_name[key2]):
    do something
```

This way you are sure you are looking at the same index in each list. You aren't looking them up by value directly though. Does that help?

Comment: not quite because I don't iterate to find the x values. They're calculated elsewhere and must be passed into the function.

Comment: If you are not iterating, how would you know you are working with the 2, 21 pair and not the 2, 24 pair? Is there another identifying factor?

Comment: Using other keys that don't repeat and that help identify the x value

Comment: But you aren't able to use the index of the keys that don't repeat to access the correct pair? Could you maybe post an example?

Comment: I think I need to use a numpy array. Thank you though

Answer (score 0):

Numpy array was a good alternative but I couldn't quite find a good answer that wouldn't require me to restructure my entire program. I solved this problem by changing the passed in parameters of the calc_target function to include index1, and index2 values. These indexes represent the indexes of x1 and x2 respectively. Then when I get the 'y values' I just use these index values.